# Pencil on a surface containing a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb P^3$ a smooth surface of degree $d$ which contains a line $L$. 
We can consider the family of hyperplane $H_t$ such that $L \subset H_t$, they are parametrized by $\mathbb P^1$.

We have a morphism $ f : X \backslash L \to \mathbb P^1$. I want to show that $f$ extends to $X$. If $F$ is the closure of a fiber of $f$, by adjunction formula we have $F^2 = 0$. So in particular, if $x \in L \cap F_t$ (where $H_t \cap X = L + F_t$) then we can define $f(x) = t$ and it extends the morphism. But I am not sure why for all $x \in L$ there is a $t$ with $x \in F_t \cap L$.

Here is my argument : consider the locus $\{y \in L : \exists t, y \in F_t\}$. This is closed and infinite so it should be everything. But this is not very geometric and I would like to see geometrically why for a fixed $y \in L$ we should find some $t$ such that $F_t$ contains y. Thanks in advance !

Edit : here is an argument why $F^2 = 0$, which is explained in these [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf) by Mile Reid about algebraic surfaces.

Let fix $H = F + L$ an hyperplane section of $X$ with $L \subset H$. By adjunction formula $L^2 = 2 - d$ since ${L^2 = K_L - K_XL = (-2 + 2\cdot 0) - (- 3 - 1 + d) = 2 - d}$. 
But $HF = d-1$ and $HL = 1$. We compute $H^2 = L^2 + F^2 + 2FL = 2 - d + 2(d-1) + F^2 = d + F^2$.

On the other hand, let us move $H$ to $H'$. $H^2 = HH' = H'(L + F) = 1 + (d-1) = d$. So $H^2 = d = d + F^2$, i.e $F^2 = 0$.

Comment: Dear Georges, we have $[F_t] \sim [F_{t'}]$ for any fiber since $H_t/H_t'$ is a rational function on $X$ with divisor $[F_t] - [F_{t'}]$. If my calcul are correct, $[F]^2 = 0$ for any fiber $F$. In particular $[F]^2 = [F_t][F_t'] = 0$, i.e the $F_t$'s are disjoint.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : I forgot to precise that $X$ was smooth ! It is probably possible to build counter-example if $X$ is singular.But if $X$ is  smooth I can use adjunction formula and I believe this is correct. I edited my question.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : dear Georges, thanks for your interest and your remark ! I edited the question with the computation. (In fact the adjunction formula is only used for compute $L^2$).
I used $F$ for talk about the divisor class of a fiber sometimes : I agree this was not clear. I also agree that there is a problem if $F_t$ and $F_{t'}$ intersect, but I believe they don't since as divisors they are equivalent to $F_{t_0}$ say. So $F_t$ does not intersect $F_{t'}$ if and only if $[F_{t_0}]^2 = 0$. And if my computation is correct this is the case.

Comment: Dear rain: congratulations for your computations, with which I completely agree: +1. And bravo for your desire to understand things geometrically. (Also: I have deleted my too skeptical comments) Au fait, êtes-vous français?

Comment: Dear Georges : thanks for your encouraging words ! Effectivement, je parle français (mais je suis belge), qu'est ce qui m'a trahi ? :)

Comment: Cher rain,  a) il n'y a pas de verbe *to precise* en anglais. On pourrait écrire (dans le contexte de votre deuxième commentaire) "I forgot to specify that $X$ was smooth"   b) Dans votre premier commentaire le lapsus  "if my calcul are correct"  à la place de  "if my calculations are correct" semble indiquer un locuteur francophone. Mais j'aurais dû me douter que votre pseudonyme *rain* pointait plutôt vers un habitant de notre cher moederland :-)

Comment: Cher Georges, je vous remercie pour les précisions ! C'est toujours un plaisir de croiser un compatriote, passez une excellente journée :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am always surprised about demanding 'geometric' arguments in 'algebraic geometry'. What is wrong with algebra?

Letting $F=H-L$, you have already said that $F^2=0$ (all linear systems on $X$). You have an exact sequence, $0\to -L\to \mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_L\to 0$ and tensoring with $F$, one has, $0\to F-L\to \mathcal{O}_X(F)\to \mathcal{O}_L(1)\to 0$. $H^0(F-L)=0$, since $F\cdot (F-L)<0$. Thus,  the map $H^0(F)\to H^0(L,\mathcal{O}(1))$ is injective. The latter is two dimesnional and clearly the first one is at least of dimension 2. Thus the map is an isomporphism. Since there exists a section of $\mathcal{O}_L(1)$ vanishing exactly at a given point, lifiting it to $F$, we are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not sure I understood why  $H^0(F)$ has dimension 2, can you explain me why ?

Comment: $H^0(F)$ has dimension at least tow, since each hyperplane containing the line gives a section and there is a two dimensional vector space of planes containing the line.